# Updating "status()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a portfolio website and the way I'm navigating through projects is by using "status". So for instance, if you click/scroll once, project 1 will reveal. Click/scroll a second time, project 2 will reveal. So on so forth.

```
<body onwheel="switchprojects()"></body>

<div class="explore-box" onClick="switchprojects()"></div>

projectStatus = 1;

function switchprojects() {
if(projectStatus==1) {
$('#bona').removeClass('float');
$('#peak').addClass('float');
projectStatus = 2;
}
else if(projectStatus==2) {
    $('#peak').removeClass('float');
    $('#trap').addClass('float');
    projectStatus = 3;
}
else if(projectStatus==3) {
    $('#trap').removeClass('float');
    $('#fp').addClass('float');
    projectStatus = 4;
}
else if(projectStatus==4) {
    $('#fp').removeClass('float');
    $('#bona').addClass('float');
    projectStatus = 1;
}
}
```

As you can see I have two separate elements, one for scrolling and one for clicking. It's working great so far, but I'm running into one issue—the status does not update between the two elements. If I scroll twice in the body for example, the same function on the clickable div won't update its status. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qozoKj Here's the codepen.

UPDATE: I'm not sure why, but when I uploaded my code to codepen, it seems to have updated the status of the clicks....but now every key on my keyboard activates the css change. I'm very confused.

Comment: Don’t use the variable name `status` in a global context, as it refers to `window.status` and will always be coerced to a string, and other weird bugs may occur.

Comment: please add complete code

Comment: Alright, thank you. I’ve changed that, still the same issue though :/

Comment: @Alpesh it’s quite long. The rest of the code is just divs and headers.

Comment: Please add sample code in which your issue can be observe, otherwise it is difficult to answer your question

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra just added a codepen :)

Comment: Instead of keydown event on body you need to use onclick try https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVMVLK

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I don't want onclick on the body. I wanted it on a button or div. It'd be odd to switch projects just by clicking anywhere in the body. I just planned on keeping onwheel for the body so they could scroll wherever their cursor was on the body.

Answer (score 0):

The reason all the keys are triggering `switchprojects()` is because you have an `onkeydown="switchprojects()"` on the `<body>`.

The reason the clicks are not listened to is that the `<div class="explore-box">` has no height or width set on it although its `position: absolute`. Mabey you should consider changing the click event to the `<div class="section">` [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MendyBerger/pen/aYgYMW)

Comment: I'm keeping onclick away from anything that doesn't resemble a button. I wouldn't want people to have to click anywhere on the page to switch the project—I can imagine that would get annoying so I just keep onwheel for the body and onclick for the button-like elements.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned to Alpesh, projectStatus seems to be in sync only in codepen and not in my normal code :\

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```js
 $(function(){
  $('#bona').addClass('float');
 });

 projectStatus = 1;

 function switchprojects() {
  if(projectStatus==1) {
  $('#bona').removeClass('float');
  $('#peak').addClass('float');
  projectStatus = 2;
 }else if(projectStatus==2) {
  $('#peak').removeClass('float');
  $('#trap').addClass('float');
  projectStatus = 3;
 }else if(projectStatus==3) {
  $('#trap').removeClass('float');
  $('#fp').addClass('float');
  projectStatus = 4;
 }else if(projectStatus==4) {
  $('#fp').removeClass('float');
  $('#bona').addClass('float');
  projectStatus = 1;
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
}
h1 {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'league';
 font-size: 8vw;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: 100;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 1);
 transition: 0s;
}
.float {
 transform: translate(0)!important;
 transition: transform 1s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 1);
 opacity: 1!important;
}
.explore-box {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 55%;
 margin-top: 70vh;
}
.explore-line {
 background-color: white;
 width: 70px;
 height: 1px;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 9pt;
 margin-right: 7pt;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 1);
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.explore-wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 float: right;
}
.explore-wrap h2 {
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 14pt;
 transform: 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body style="background-color: #141219;" onwheel="switchprojects()">
  <div class="section">
  <h1 id="bona" style="transform: translateY(10%); opacity: 0;">BONA COFFEE</h1>
   <h1 id="peak" style="transform: translateY(10%); opacity: 0;">PEAK EXPLORATIONS</h1>
   <h1 id="trap" style="transform: translateY(10%); opacity: 0;">TRAP MAGAZINE</h1>
   <h1 id="fp" style="transform: translateY(10%); opacity: 0;">FIELD & PANTRY</h1>
    
    
    <div class="explore-box" onClick="switchprojects()">
   <div class="explore-line"></div>
   <div class="explore-wrap">
    <h2>View</h2>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="explore-wrap" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
    <h2>Project</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As You say I have added the click event on **View Projects** instead of body

Comment: Yeah, I can see that the projectStatus on both elements are in sync. However, that only seems to be the case on codepen. They still do not sync up on my regular code.

Comment: Where you have declared **projectStatus** in your code ?

Comment: I was recommended earlier to change "status" to something else, for reasons dealing with bugs.